# android wifi application crash

Tags: android

I have this code:

```
    List<ScanResult> vAll = null;
    WifiManager vMainWifi = null;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_wi_fi);

        vMainWifi = (WifiManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        vAll = getWiFi();
    }   
    public void btnViewWiFI_onClick(View v) {
        TextView vTmpTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvRetele);
        String vString = "WiFi:";
        List<String> vLista = getWiFiString();
        if (vLista != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < vLista.size(); i++)
                vString += "\n\t" + vLista.get(i);
        }
        vTmpTextView.setText(vString);
    }
    List<ScanResult> getWiFi() {
        if (vAll != null)
            return vAll;
        if (vMainWifi.isWifiEnabled())
            return vMainWifi.getScanResults();
        else {
            vMainWifi.setWifiEnabled(true);
            return vMainWifi.getScanResults();
        }
    }
    List<String> getWiFiString() {
        List<String> vTmp = null;
        if (vAll == null)
            vAll = getWiFi();
        if (vAll != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < vAll.size(); i++)
                vTmp.add(vAll.get(i).BSSID + ", " + vAll.get(i).SSID);
        }
        return vTmp;
    }
```

In layout xml

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvRetele"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="94dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnViewWiFI"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="145dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="233dp"
        android:onClick="btnViewWiFI_onClick"
        android:text="@string/viewWiFi" />
```

In Manifest file i have this

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
```

If I try to debug this I get empty list, probably becouse I get error for WiFi Networks, but when I upload to phone and install this application I get crash when I pres the button.
What I do wrong?

Comment: show the error message or a point will be docked from your question. Its in the logcat, and it will be red.  Find it and select it and post it to this board asap.

Comment: Its more important that you learn to read the log file than fix this particular problem.  You will find the exact spot if you click on the first or second line in red that contains your package name.  Crashes should also have the word fatal as well as be in red.

Comment: f you don't see logcat goto eclipse --> window-->show view --> logcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not instantiating the list vTmp in getWiFiString() ! you get a NullPointerException when trying to add elements to it.

What you probably need is:

```
List<String> vTmp = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: this was the problem, in c++ vector<> do not need to init

Comment: Ahm, and you select an answer which tells you to use the logcat? I could also have done that, instead of taking the time to read your code, it would have been easier... (!)

Answer (score 0):

Read your log file.  Find where it says fatal.  Find the line that has your package name in it.  It will probably say null pointer exception.  Goto the line and make sure that the item has a value and is not null.  Set breakpoint before the crash line and check the value of everything.  This is an answer that will not only solve this problem but many more you will encounter.

If you don't see logcat goto eclipse --> window-->show view --> logcat

Comment: This is indeed a helpful advice, and will make xnl96's life easier, but should be a comment/is not an answer to the question.